# Why my onmessage method can't receive event data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I'm using websocket to make an easy web app.

My server program has a very easy function that when it receives a message from a client, it'll return the same message to the client.

My code is below:

```
class Seat extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            'seatLabel' : 'Empty'
        }
        this.Message = this.Message.bind(this);
        this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/');
        this.ws.onmessage = this.Message;
        this.ws.onopen = function(){
            this.send("sadf");
        }
    }

    Message(e){
        alert(e.data);
    }

    handleClick(p) {
        this.ws.send(`${p.pname}`)
        if (this.props.sitdown(p)) {
            p.sit = !p.sit;
            this.setState({
                'seatLabel': p.sit ? p.pname : "Empty"
            })
        }

    }

    render(){
        return (<div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, this.props.user)}>{this.state.seatLabel}</div>)
    }
}
```

'onmessage' event is triggered when the object 'ws' is 'onopen' status, I can receive the message from the server.

But when I clicked the div to send a message, I can't receive the response message.

So I want to know what happened, why I can't receive the message.

Comment: Don't post a picture, post your actual code.

Comment: @ErikGodard OK!

Comment: what is your server code?